# Can I override/handle keyDown in fragment without put into Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a `fragment` that's in an AAR, and the main `activity` that holds this `fragment` is in another APK depending on this AAR.

I could `override` the `handleKeyDown()` in the activity, but is there any way that I can directly override/handle the `keyDown` in the fragment since there're multiple fragments for this `activity`.

p.s. I need to capture all sorts of `keyevent` e.g. up, down, left & right, **not only back button**.

Also I tried to implement `KeyEvent.Callback` but it's not catching any keyevent when I navigate thru UI.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1: Create a custom interface, let's say KeyEventListener**

```
public interface MyKeyEventListener {
    boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
}
```

**Step2: Add field currentFragment in Activity, which will be updated whenever you switch fragment. Basically it will hold the currently visible fragment**

```
Fragment currentFragment;
currentFragment = here getCurrentFragment() etc;
```

**Step3: Implement MyKeyEventListener in your fragments. You can skip interface implementation in any fragment**

```
 public class Fragment1 implements MyKeyEventListener {
     @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         //do whatever you want in onKeyDown
     }
 }
```

**Step4: Override onKeyDown in your Activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(currentFragment != null && currentFragment instanceof MyKeyEventListener) {
        ((MyKeyEventListener) currentFragment).onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```